# This function is undefined: IF (Emacs Lisp)

Tags: function, lisp

Why is this telling me that "if" is an undefined function?

```
    (defun sum (n m)
      (if (and (integerp n) (integerp m))
         (cond
          ((zerop n) m)
          ((zerop m) n)
            (if (< n 0)
              (sum (+ n 1) (- m 1))
              (sum (- n 1) (+ m 1))))
        nil))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conventional formatting applied and some comments, your code is:

```
(defun sum (n m)
  ;; if n and m are integers
  (if (and (integerp n) (integerp m))
      ;; then …
      (cond
        ;; first case: if the expression `(zerop n)` is true, then return m
        ((zerop n) m)
        ;; second case: if the expression `(zerop m)` is true, then return n
        ((zerop m) n)
        ;; third case: if the expression `if` is true, then
        ;; evaluate (< n 0), evaluate (sum (+ n 1) (- m 1)),
        ;; and return (sum (- n 1) (+ m 1))
        (if (< n 0)
            (sum (+ n 1) (- m 1))
            (sum (- n 1) (+ m 1))))
      ;; else return nil
      nil))
```

When I evaluate this definition in emacs and then try to evaluate, e.g., `(sum 2 3)`, the error I get is actually:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable if)
  (cond ((zerop n) m) ((zerop m) n) (if (< n 0) (sum ... ...) (sum ... ...)))
  (if (and (integerp n) (integerp m)) (cond (... m) (... n) (if ... ... ...)) nil)
  sum(2 3)
  eval((sum 2 3))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

because the third clause is trying to take the value of `if` as a variable.  I expect that what you wanted was an *otherwise* clause.  Make the third clause the same form as the others, with a condition that will always be true, e.g., `t`:

```
(defun sum (n m)
  (if (and (integerp n) (integerp m))
      (cond
        ((zerop n) m)
        ((zerop m) n)
        (t (if (< n 0)
               (sum (+ n 1) (- m 1))
               (sum (- n 1) (+ m 1)))))
      nil))
```

Then `(sum 2 3)` returns `5`.